# Android: Saving contents of a listview onSaveInstanceState

Tags: android, listview

Is there an built in way to save the contents of a listView as part of onSaveInstanceState to then restore later?  I want the listView to look the same if the user hit the back button and now onCreate is being called again.

Answer (score 4):

If you set your activity's [`launchMode`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) to `singleTask`, then (unless the application was terminated / gc called upon) your data (list) will be preserved.

This way your device will hold only one running instance of your application at a time, so when you "launch it again" no matter from where, if it's already running in the background, then that instance will show up (with the latest data).

If there is a risk that your application was finished, and you still need the latest list of data to show up, this solution won't work. 
But you could give a try to `SharedPreferences`: save the current data to the application's `SharedPreferences`, and restore it from there when launching it.

If it's ok, to have the predefined new list on each clean start of the application, but when getting it into foreground, you need the last seen items in your list, you should use the `savedInstanceState` parameter of your `onCreate` method:

```
private static final String MYLISTKEY = "myListLabels";
private ArrayList<String> listLabels = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState.containsKey(MYLISTKEY))
    {
        listLabels = savedInstanceState.getStringArrayList(MYLISTKEY);
    }
    else
    {
        // TODO: populate explicitely your list
    }
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
{
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putStringArrayList(MYLISTKEY, listLabels);
}
```

where `listLabels` contains the labels for your list. 
It's not necessary for them to be of type `String`, you can put any type inside your `Bundle`.

Comment: When they hit the back button it does appear to be destroyed...onCreate gets called again.  I have already tried just this change, and it did not work.  Does that sound right?

Comment: That might be because you populate explicitly your list inside the `onCreate` method. Please see my update to work with the `savedInstanceState` in the `onCreate` of your activity.

Comment: onSaveInstanceState does not appear to be called when the user hits the back button.  It appears to be only called when the activity is paused, not killed.  So, I think I have use something more persistent.  The reason for this, is the user complaint is they hit the back button and then they later relaunch the app and the listview no longer has their contents in it.

Answer (score 0):

When the user hits the back button the activity is always destroyed, so there will not be any restoring from savedinstance.

[Android Training](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html)

> When your activity is destroyed because the user presses Back or the activity finishes itself, the system's concept of that Activity instance is gone forever because the behavior indicates the activity is no longer needed.